# Good approach to sorting strings which contain number ie test 1, test10, test2

Tags: c#, string, sorting

I am using C#, .NET 4.7

I have 3 strings ie.

```
[test.1, test.10, test.2]
```

I need to sort them to get:

```
test.1
test.2
test.10
```

I may get other strings like

```
[1test, 10test, 2test]
```

which should produce:

```
1test
2test
10test
```

using same approach.

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23865465/106159) help?

Comment: @MatthewWatson, thank you for this. Am studying. Not sure about Pinvoke, as I am using ASP.NET MVC, but other interesting options in there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Parse the number using Regex and then sort the string. For example,

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"\d+");
var result = strArray.Where(x=>re.Match(x).Success)
                .Select(x=> new { Key = int.Parse(re.Match(x).Value),Value = x})
                .OrderBy(x=>x.Key).Select(x=>x.Value);
```

Where strArray is the collection of strings.

Please note in the above case, you are ignoring string which doesn't have a numeric part (as it wasn't described in OP). The numeric part of string is parsed using Regex, which is then used for sorting the collection.

Example,
Input

```
var strArray = new string[]{"1test", "10test", "2test"};
```

Output

```
1test 
2test 
10test
```

Input

```
var strArray = new string[]{"test.1", "test.10", "test.2"};
```

Outpuyt

```
test.1 
test.2 
test.10
```

Answer (score 2):

For your first array you can do

```
var array = new[] { "test.1", "test.10", "test.2" };

var sortedArray = array.OrderBy(s => int.Parse(s.Substring(5, s.Length - 5)));
```

For the second array

```
var array = new[] { "1test", "2test", "10test" };

var sortedArray = array.OrderBy(s => int.Parse(s.Substring(0, s.Length - 4)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. It uses SortedDictionary which always sort it's items by key when they are inserted.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SortedDictionary<int, string> tuples = new SortedDictionary<int, string>();
            string[] stringsToSortByNumbers = { "test.1", "test.10", "test.2" };

            foreach (var item in stringsToSortByNumbers)
            {
                int numeric = Convert.ToInt32(new String(item.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray()));
                tuples.Add(numeric, item);
            }

            foreach (var item in tuples)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
```